# Install Nuget package using "dotnet add package -s" fail when specify private Github Nuget feed

Tags: c#, .net, github, nuget, command-line-interface

I have a private feed from GitHub that I added to `Nuget.config` file:

```xml
<add key="github" value="https://nuget.pkg.github.com/..." />
```

I can confirm it works by using `dotnet nuget list source` (see screenshot below).

However when running `dotnet add package -s github PackageName`, it fails with "There are no versions available for the package" error. Removing the `-s github` works (and it installs from the Private feed if it is on the top).

[image]

Although I can manually run it for myself (removing `-s`), I am writing a script to install it for other developers. I need to reliably install it from the private feed even if it's not on the top of the list. There may be packages in `nuget.org` with the same name in our private feed.

Why does specifying package source with `-s` not work? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-package#options) are saying:

> `-s|--source <SOURCE>`
>
> The URI of the NuGet package source to use during the restore operation.

So I'd expect the command to be like this:

```
dotnet add package -s https://nuget.pkg.github.com/... PackageName
```

Comment: Ahh... that's what I have been missing. I went through that page at least twice but didn't notice that detail. Thank you so much. It's really dumb to have to specify the full URL though.

Comment: Just FYI: in our organization the only package source (within `nuget.config`) is our private Artifactory instance. On this instance we're hosting both our company packages as well as public packages, which get mirrored from nuget.org. Thereby you don't have to specify `-s` every time. Maybe you're looking for a similar setting?

Comment: yes if I can do that that's great. How do you mirror nuget.org packages though? Wouldn't that be huge and incur additional cost since you store Nuget packages in your private Github?

Comment: Not *all* packages from nuget.org are mirrored. Whenever a request for `MyPackage` enters Artifactory, it checks whether this package is present (it could be an internal package or already mirrored). If not, it is downloaded and persisted. So only on demand

Comment: Ah I see. I don't think this flow would apply well for my company though. We'd like to use many public packages as well. Thanks for the info anyway.

Comment: Same for us, 99% of our used package are coming from nuget.org. But the process is completely transparent to our .NET devs - they don't even recognize that packages are mirrored, because Artifactory handles this on its own